# Mysql database not showing the current date for NOW() function

Tags: mysql

I am using the NOW() with insert query so that I can get the currentTime when the query is triggered. But I get a time of 12 hours back in the database. How can I get the current Time ? Please help.

Comment: check your mysql timzone.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: put your comment to the proper answer so OP can check it as valid ;-)

Comment: Shakti Singh is correct - [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html]

Comment: How am I suppose to change it? I When i fired the query at 12.40 pm on 22nd jan its showing me 2011-01-22 00:11:05 . I am in India and the timezone is +5:30 gmt. But the value in database is 12 hrs offset

Comment: @dilip: may be because server has its own offset of GMT -07:00 (`-7 - 5:30 == -12:30; 12:40pm - 12:30 == 12:10am`)? ;-) Try to follow my advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766544/mysql-database-not-showing-the-current-date-for-now-function/4766561#4766561

Comment: can u let me know how to set the server timezone.

Comment: @dilip: you don't need to set server timezone. All the information is in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen if the Timezone in your server configuration is different. Assuming that you are on a shared host, try adding the following lines when you are querying:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+05:30';");
```

Source: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Running_web_scripts_in_your_Timezone

Else try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Colombo
```

A full list of all the Timezones http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html - this can be a better source, imho.

Comment: "Else try adding the following to your .htaccess file" --- how does `.htaccess` related to **mysql**?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @zerkms - It's all about server configuration. If you're unclear on this I recommend you to read http://support.hostgator.com/articles/getting-started/general-help/can-i-change-the-server-clock-or-time-zone and http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Running_web_scripts_in_your_Timezone

Comment: `.htaccess` is only related to **apache**. If you're unclear I recommend you to think about the fact that there could not be apache at server at all, since it is on another server. Also I recommend you to check your advices before give them.

Comment: I entered that line in my php file and it works. But what if I want my server to have same time offset for every php file. I dont want to include that line in every php file. How to configure my server's default timezone?

Answer (score 3):

Perform this query right after you've been connected to the database:

```
SET time_zone = '+05:30';
```

Where it is your valid timezone offset in the quotes.

Comment: What if I want to set the timezone for every connection that i make. i.e I dont wanna include anything in the php file. Cant we change some configuration settings of the database from command line?

Comment: @dilip: create **one function** that connects mysql and sets up everything you need and use it everywhere. Since you're not mysql administrator - you cannot change anything in this case.

Comment: But I have bought the web space so I am allowed to view all the configuration files. Cant I change some settings in configuration files?

Comment: @dilip: ask your provider support, whether you can change config or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOURS

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do, in your SQL query:

DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR);

This will take the current time and <s>subtract</s> add 12 hours <s>from</s> to it.